# persistent tcp socket connection in c

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have a `C` service application that use `tcp socket` for connection to a server. The server sends data now and then. Also my application sends a hearbeat every 15 seconds. But sometimes it disconnects while server seems to think the connection is live. Now if I try to reconnect the server refuses as it holds only one connection for the client at a time.

What is the best way to hold a persistent `tcp connection`?

Edit:
The server usually disconnects after 2 min without heartbeat. So after I find my connection is closed it takes 2min for me to successfully reconnect. I want to minimize this time.

Comment: What are your expectation of persistence ( like cable disconnection, or access point goes down ), I think your issue has no solution.

Comment: @dvhh Issues are mainly during sending heartbeat which sometimes gets sigpipe or other problems. The server seems to think the connection isn't closed.

Comment: isn't there some watchdog on the server closing the connection when it didn't receive the heartbeat ?

Comment: Show some code, your question is too general... Anyway, program defined heartbeat is not a very good idea, yo'd better use UTO TCP parameter.

Comment: Are you asking how to fix the client or how to fix the server or how to sanely design a scheme where a TCP disconnect can be discovered by either side ... or what? Is the protocol you are using one that you designed?

Comment: You could always fix both. Make your server into a real one, (ie. can handle multiple, independent connections),  and use TCP keepalive to identify, and then close down, any left-over 'half-connections'.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am asking If I can always make a close call to disconnect the server in my scenerio or equivalent.

Comment: @dvhh server connection closing detail in edit.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunes could you give me a detail on user timeout parameter option. I use apache tomcat server.

Comment: Why not just have the server disconnect if it doesn't receive a heartbeat for, say, 30 seconds.

Comment: If the server doesn't detect the client disconnect there is something wrong with it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it has been changed to 1min already. 30 seconds should work too.

Comment: Also I am not sure about the default sending timeout. So when will server be sure that the connection is closed?

Comment: @EJP As far as I can understand EPIPE is recieved while calling socket send not socket recieve. So the server is not probably understanding it while it is recieving.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix is probably for the server to allow a new connection to *replace* an old connection rather than rejecting it. That would still keep only one connection to each client at a time.

Comment: Although this is a viable solution this will add vulnerability for DOS attack.

Comment: @nomem How do you figure?

Comment: If a connection always replaces old one then if multiple client try to connect with same username password my server will be busy doing that. Now If a connection is not replaced then other requests will be ignored.

Comment: Well, you have to drop one connection or the other. I don't see why it makes a major difference which you drop when it comes to DOS attacks.